# $pull deletes everything from Array of Objects

Tags: express, mongoose, pull

I'm using $pull to remove items from nested subdocuments, but if I want to remove 1 item from the Array, it removes all items from Array

What am I doing wrong?

I do the $pull here with ExpressJS:

```
getController.deleteRec = function(req,res,collection){
  var id = req.params.id;
  console.log(id);
  collection.updateOne({'subitem.messages._id': id}, {$pull: {'subitem.$.messages': {"subitem.$.messages": id}}}).
    then(function(result){
      console.log(result);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pull like this:

```
{ 
  $pull: {'subitem.messages: {'_id': id}}
}
```

Assuming that 'subitem.messages' is the array you want to pull the element that has {_id : id} from.